# Matplotlib align tick positions with image pixel boundaries

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating images with `numpy`, using `matplotlib` to visualize regions I care about, and then using `pillow` to save them as PNGs. When I am plotting the images, the tick marks and labels are centered on the pixels instead of on pixel boundaries:

[image]

Is there a way I could left/top justify the ticks and labels? I've found info on moving the labels, but not the ticks.

I have also tried using the axis interface with `ax.major_ticklabels.set_ha("left")` and `ax.major_ticklabels.set_va("top")` as documented [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/userdemo/demo_ticklabel_alignment.html?highlight=centered%20ticklabels) but can't get it to work. I expected `0` to be right on the edge and`1` right in the middle but I can't get this behavior.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image_size = (2, 2)
data = np.zeros(image_size)
data[0][0] = 255
data[1][1] = 255
plt.xticks([0, 1])
plt.yticks([0, 1])
plt.imshow(Image.fromarray(data).convert("L"))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_size = (2, 2)
data = np.zeros(image_size)
data[0][0] = 255
data[1][1] = 255
x= [0,.5]
y= [0,.5]
labels = (0,1)
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.yticks(y, labels)
plt.imshow(Image.fromarray(data).convert("L"),extent = [0, 1,0 ,1])
plt.show()
```